# Highlight table view cell on click

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I place a single table view cell on my view using interface builder and add an accessory type, a selection color and enable user interaction.

[image]

However when I click on the cell nothing happens.

Why isn't the whole cell highlighted, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In Interface Builder: select custom cell, set option `Selection` to `Gray` or `Blue`.
2. Programmatically : set property of cell `selectionStyle` to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue` or `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray`.
3. Also you can set custom selection color:

   `cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];`

   `cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:CC(213) green:CC(221) blue:CC(232) alpha:1.0];`